# Von Neumann universe implies Foundation

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Suppose we are working in $\mathsf{ZF-Foundation}$. Additionally, let us assume that $V = \bigcup\{V_{\alpha} | \alpha \in \mathsf{Ord}\}$ holds. Now I want to show that this implies Foundation. I am not sure if my proof works:

Let $x$ be a nonempty set, i.e. $x \in V$. Then $x \in V_\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \mathsf{Ord}$. Now, pick $y \in x$ with $\beta$ minimal such that $y \in V_\beta$. This is possible since $\mathsf{Ord}$ is a wellfounded. Now, if $z \in x \cap y$, then $z \in y$ and hence $z \in V_\gamma$ for some $\gamma < \beta$. But since $z \in x$ as well, this contradicts the minimality of $y$. Hence, $x \cap y = \emptyset$.

Does this proof work? I am unsure, if I can use that $\mathsf{Ord}$ is wellfounded. But this shouldn't depend on Foundation, right?

Comment: OK, if the proof depends on the well-foundedness of $\mathsf{Ord}$, the obvious strategy would be to also prove this.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo But how can I show that $\mathsf{Ord}$ is well-founded without assuming Foundation? I found [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/441420/111080) answer stating that in order to prove this we need a definition of the ordinals "in a way that ensures that the ordinals are well-ordered". So does this mean I am not able to prove that the ordinals are wellfounded without foundation/regularity? My definition is that the ordinals are the transitive sets which are linearly ordered and this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should use the (redundant under Foundation) definition of ordinal that says "transitive and _wellordered_ by $\in$". This is the one you need in this context.